# $\int \frac {x \, dx}{\sqrt{ -7-8x-x^2}}$

Tags: integration

What is $\displaystyle\int \frac {x \, dx}{\sqrt{ -7-8x-x^2}}$

I only got this  one
$$ \int \frac{x \, dx}{\sqrt{ 9 - (x+4)^2}}$$

And Im stuck here i dont know what to do next.

Comment: How did you get rid of that square root? Shouldn't it still be there?

Comment: I suppose that you forgot a square root within the second integral.

Comment: Yes i forgot to put an Square root .Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Setting $u = -x^2-8x-7,$ you have $du = (-2x -8)\,dx,$ so $(x+4)\,dx = \dfrac{-du} 2.$ So write
$$
\int \frac{x\,dx}{\sqrt{-x^2-8x-7}} = \int\frac{(x+4)\,dx}{\sqrt{-x^2-8x-7}} + \int \frac{-4\,dx}{\sqrt{-x^2-8x-7}}.
$$
Use the substitution above to do the *first* integral on the right side.

For the second integral, you have
$$
\int\frac{-4\, dx}{\sqrt{9 - (x+4)^2}} = -4 \int \frac{dx/3}{\sqrt{1 - \left( \frac{x+4} 3 \right)^2}}.
$$
So let $\sin\theta = \dfrac{x+4} 3,$ and then $\cos\theta\,d\theta = \dfrac{dx}3.$ The radical becomes $\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta} = \cos\theta.$

Comment: Thank you. I get it know.

Comment: @Madisson : Notice that you can "accept" the answer.

Comment: I already solve the last part of it. Thank you. I only need the upper part of your solution to guide me.

Comment: How can I " accept" the answer? What do you mean?

Comment: @Madisson : See this page: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. From $$\int \frac{x \, dx}{\sqrt{ 9 - (x+4)^2}}$$ and substitution $$(x+4)=3\sin(t)$$ $$dx=3\cos(t)dt$$ we get to the integral $$  \int (3\sin(t)-4) \, dt.$$ Upon integration we get $$ -3\cos(t) -4t +c$$Since $$t = \arcsin((x+4)/3)$$ the final answer turns out to be $$- {\sqrt{9 - (x+4)^2}}-4\arcsin((x+4)/3) + C$$

Comment: How come there is a -3 there? If you differentiate it you will not get the original given.

Comment: Thanks Madisson. I fixed it.

Comment: Welcome. That's  also the answer that i get.

Comment: I am still trying to learn MathJax and occasionally I make mistakes. I should have been  more careful.

Comment: It's okay. I'm also new in integration. I'm just in second level in college.